# How to hide some categories in latest product module Opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

So I have Opencart 1.5.6 and I need to hide one category to not show up in latest product module... How can I fix php to do that and not use any 3rd party modules?

I understand it is somewhere in `catalog\controller\module\latest.php`, so here is my code:

```
    <?php
class ControllerModuleLatest extends Controller {
    protected function index($setting) {
        $this->language->load('module/latest');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $this->data['products'] = array();

        $data = array(
            'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'start' => 0,
            'limit' => $setting['limit']
        );

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
            } else {
                $image = false;
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = $result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }

            $this->data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'      => $image,
                'name'       => $result['name'],
                'price'      => $price,
                'special'    => $special,
                'rating'     => $rating,
                'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
            );
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/latest.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/latest.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/latest.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must get product categories:

```
$get_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
```

Then with `in_array` function, check if product has not a certain category, here for example 24 is the id of category, we don't want to show its products:

```
if(!in_array(24, $categories))
```

so your file will be:

```
<?php
    class ControllerModuleLatest extends Controller {
        protected function index($setting) {
            $this->language->load('module/latest');

            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

            $this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $this->load->model('tool/image');

            $this->data['products'] = array();

            $data = array(
                'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'start' => 0,
                'limit' => $setting['limit']
            );

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['image_width'], $setting['image_height']);
                } else {
                    $image = false;
                }

                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if ((float)$result['special']) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = $result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $get_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
                $categories = array();
                foreach($get_categories as $category){
                    $categories[] = $category['category_id'];
                }

                if(!in_array(24, $categories)){
                    $this->data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                        'thumb'      => $image,
                        'name'       => $result['name'],
                        'price'      => $price,
                        'special'    => $special,
                        'rating'     => $rating,
                        'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                        'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
                    );
                }
            }

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/latest.tpl')) {
                $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/latest.tpl';
            } else {
                $this->template = 'default/template/module/latest.tpl';
            }

            $this->render();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I just tried to add one and then couple of categories by: if(!in_array(83|88|94|92|95|90|91|86|78|84|89|93|87|85,  but no result still can see those categories in this module! :( any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works but only when i hide one category! How to hide couple of them? I tried by comma and also 83|88|94 no result! :(

Comment: You can use something like this `if(!in_array(24, $categories) && !in_array(20, $categories) && !in_array(18, $categories)){`

Comment: Your welcome, if my answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: After i added this code it hide all categories!!! There is some mistake but where? :( if(!in_array(84, $categories) && !in_array(89, $categories) && !in_array(93, $categories) && !in_array(87, $categories) && !in_array(85, $categories) && !in_array(83, $categories) && !in_array(88, $categories) && !in_array(94, $categories) && !in_array(92, $categories) && !in_array(95, $categories) && !in_array(90, $categories) && !in_array(91, $categories) && !in_array(86, $categories) && !in_array(78, $categories)){ With one category it works but not with couple... :(